# I have Issue with transform property on safari [10.1.2], all other browser working fine

Tags: css, user-interface, safari, css-transforms

Showing in safari browser

[image: Showing in safari browser]

[image]

Here is the fiddle witch is working fine on Chrome but not on Safari.
[Please check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azhrhussain/zLczdeua/6/)

If i remove the `transform-origin: left` from `.points-list li` it work fine but hover state disturb with it.

Comment: Have you tried to add `-webkit-` to `transform` / `transform-origin` ?

Comment: Yeah. I have tried but the result remain same.